# Marker with label google map

Tags: google-maps, marker

i want to place a label below the marker (my marker is a circle). Now it is in the middle and it is not what I want, my code:

```
            var circle = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: circle,
            map: map,
            icon: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/circle.png'; ?>',
            label: "My city"
        });
```

[image: marker]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `labelOrigin` property of the [`Icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) appropriately for your icon.

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon):

> **labelOrigin**   | Type:  Point
>   The origin of the label relative to the top-left corner of the icon image, if a label is supplied by the marker. By default, the origin is located in the center point of the image.